# Short Script for Converting Google Forms Data to PDF not sending email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am working with [this tutorial](http://tjhouston.com/2012/03/merge-info-from-google-forms-to-pdf-document-and-send-via-email/) to try to convert data submited from a google form to a PDF. Problem is, I am not getting any emails. The spreadsheet updates fine, but no emails.

I am prety comfortable with the coding but I never have used Google Drive scripting. It seems some of the code may be outdated. I changed "DocsList" to "DriveApp" via find and replace and I changed "MailApp" to gmail app.

I am not sure where to go from here or even how to use the debugger when waiting for a formsubmit event. Any advice would be greatly apreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
//:שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל יהוה אֱלֹהֵינוּ יהוה אֶחָד
//Christian Shields (ChristianShields@gmail.com)
//Job Application Google Form to PDF converter
//11/2/15

//get the document from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1wgkvO-1xrVGJkD-JJ2FMRbQj_bfGu7qFAa6pTEJ61Cw";
var docName = "NewCherryHillJobApplication";

function onFormSubmit(e){
  //set the email address where the finished document will go.
  var docs_email = "ChristianShields@gmail.com";

  //get information from the newly submited form
  var full_name = e.values[2];
  var age = e.values[3];
  var address = e.values[4];
  var phone = e.values[5];
  var alt_phone = e.values[6];
  var email

  //Get the document template and copy it as a new temp document. Save the document ID's
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
  .getId();

  //open the temp document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  //go to the temp documents body
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  //replace the text in the temp document
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', full_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAge', age);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPhone', phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAltPhone', alt_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyEmail', email);

  //save and close the temp document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  //convert the temp document to pdf
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  //Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "New Doc's Job Application Submited Online";
  var body = "A new job application has been recieved from " + full_name + ". Primary phone number for this applicant is: " + phone + "";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(docs_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

  // Delete temp file
  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true); 
} //End of dunction "onFormSubmit
```

Comment: You won't be able to use the debugger with any of the triggers.  You will need to run the function that gets triggered, *from* the code editor.  Obviously, when you do that, there is no data coming in from the form, so you can "hard code" simulated data for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
```

Uses a method named `getActiveSection()`.  That method is not in the documentation, and it doesn't appear in the auto-complete list.  It doesn't exist.  Strangely enough, it doesn't produce an error.  I can't find it in any deprecated list.

I just ran your code, and it sent me an email with a pdf file.  I commented out some parts.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  //set the email address where the finished document will go.
  var docs_email = "your_email@gmail.com";

  //get information from the newly submited form
  var full_name = 'First Last';
  var age = '99';
  var address = '77 Maple Grove';
  var phone = '800 Call Joe';
  var alt_phone = 'none';
  var email

  //Get the document template and copy it as a new temp document. Save the document ID's
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById('Your Document ID Here')
  .makeCopy('Novem3'+' for '+full_name)
  .getId();

  //open the temp document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  //go to the temp documents body
  copyDoc.getBody()
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  //replace the text in the temp document
/*  copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', full_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAge', age);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPhone', phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAltPhone', alt_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyEmail', email);
*/
  //save and close the temp document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  //convert the temp document to pdf
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

  //Attach PDF and send the email
  var subject = "New Doc's Job Application Submited Online";
  var body = "A new job application has been recieved from " + full_name + ". Primary phone number for this applicant is: " + phone + "";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(docs_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

  // Delete temp file
  //DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true); 
} //End of dunction "onFormSubmit
```

Comment: I got your email as well! I was so confused when that email came in, let me spend some time going over your code but this might just do it, thanks!

Comment: I didn't really do much, but put in a valid document ID, and "Hard Code" the form information.  And I commented out all the `replaceText()` stuff.  Even though the code ran with that `getActiveSection()` method, I'd replace that will something else.  I don't think that the `DriveApp` or `MailApp` usage has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: I was able to get the emails working in debugger. I even got the text replace stuff to work. getActiveSection() was replaces with getBody() in around 2013. [I found the release notes that mention the change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013#april_15_2013). However I am still not getting the emails live, I am wondering if the function onFormSubmit(e) is not what I want.

Comment: Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do to link this script to my form or my form's spreadsheet?

Comment: There are two categories of triggers, simple and installable.  [Google documentation - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started)  There is no ***simple*** trigger for `onFormSubmit(e)`.  The only way you can trigger an On Form Submit trigger is by setting it up through the code editor.  If you haven't done that, use the *Resources* menu, and *Current Project Triggers*.

Comment: Aha! It worked! I was using a tutorial that left that part out, thanks for humoring me and getting me past the basics! You rock!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you are sending the emails to yourself they may not turn up in your inbox, so take a look at "Sent Mail" to see if they are there.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. I checked sent and "All mail" (Or "Done" in the case of Inbox) still nothing.

Comment: Ok, once I got debugging working I sure enough only found the emails in sent mail. that saved me some good time! Still working on solving the underlying problem though. Thanks!